# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (74,58) (66,) (74,58)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

After writing this code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

The **error** is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-55872220c4e4> in <module>()
      5 X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
      6 
----> 7 X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in transform(self, X)
    387                         force_all_finite="allow-nan")
    388 
--> 389         X *= self.scale_
    390         X += self.min_
    391         return X

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (74,58) (66,) (74,58)
```

Help, please

Comment: Something's wrong with the dimensions of your `X_train` or `X_test`. Can you share with us, how you create these arrays? What are their shapes? I guess that `X_train` has dims `(74,58)`, and `X_test` has shape `(66,)`, which clearly don't match.

Comment: Yes for sure something went wrong, my x_train.shape is (292,66) and x_test.shape is (74,58). So how do i set them to remove the error?

Comment: You haven't shown us the code that generates `X_train, X_test`. They need to have the same dimensions. Did they come from a split, or a pipeline, or what? Show us that code. That's what you have to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because [`MinMaxScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) is expecting `X_test` to have the same number of feature-dimensions as the data it was trained with, in your case: 66.

More formally, it must hold that `X_train.shape[1]==X_test.shape[1]`. This is the common assumption for most (if not all) types of estimators (transformers, classifiers, regressors) provided by `sklearn`. In other words, the configuration of the feature space is required to be the same for the training and test data.

To fix your problem, you need to revise how you create `X_train` and `X_test`. In `sklearn` data matrices, rows represent *samples* and columns represent *features* or *predictors*. When splitting the complete dataset `X_all` into `X_train` and `X_test`, one usually splits the rows into two *distinct* subsets, while keeping the dimensions of the feature space (i.e. the number of columns) fixed. One way to achieve this is for example by using [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test = train_test_split(X_all, test_size = 0.3, random_state=42)
```

If you work in the context of machine-learning or statistics, you probably want to embed data splitting in a cross-validation scheme. `sklearn` offers several such validation schemes, depending on the type of problem you are working on. See [this tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_cv_indices.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-cv-indices-py) for some examples.